# How to Set Session Variable when User Login in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, session-variables, laravel-5.3

Invoice app development is going on using Laravel. I store date and amount format for every users in `settings` table.

When user login to their account how to set `Session` variable? Please give any suggestions. I am using Laravel 5.3.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#storing-data

Answer (score 21):

Of course the docs tell us how to [store session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#storing-data)*, but they don't address the OP's question regarding storing session data **at login**. You have a couple options but I think the clearest way is to override the AuthenticatesUsers trait's authenticated method.

Add the override to your LoginController:

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $this->setUserSession($user);
}
```

Then you can set your session up as:

```
protected function setUserSession($user)
{
    session(
        [
            'last_invoiced_at' => $user->settings->last_invoiced_at,
            'total_amount_due' => $user->settings->total_amount_due
        ]
    );
}
```

If you want to be a bit more clever you can create a listener for the Login or Authenticated events and set up the session when one of those [events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#events)* fires.

Create a listener such as SetUpUserSession:

```
<?php

namespace app\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;

class SetUserSession
{
    /**
     * @param  Login $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        session(
            [
                'last_invoiced_at' => $event->user->settings->last_invoiced_at, 
                'total_amount_due' => $event->user->settings->total_amount_due
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

*Links go to 5.4 but this hasn't changed from 5.3.

Comment: Perfect answer. It's worked for me. Now I can set user profile information in session correctly

Comment: This works but the session was not persistent for example user closes the browser and re-opens the page I had to use Middleware like this example https://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale

Comment: @JoelDavey app/config/session.php     
'lifetime' => 43200, // 30 days
'expire_on_close' => false,

Comment: @shawn-lindstrom Tried to replicate your SetUserSession example, but Login event not being caught upon User Login. Do i need to register the Auth\Event\Login in the EventServiceProvider or should it work as above with nothing extra? Ty

Comment: @Greenie it is necessary to register the Listener in EventServiceProvider, at least when working in 6.x. Strange since the docs seem to indicate discovery should be automatic.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the Auth class to manage user data, like this:

```
public function index(){   
  $user_id = Auth::user()->id;  
}
```

But you have to add 'use Auth;' before class declaration. Then you can add any data to session variable.

Comment: That's just how you would get data, but the question asks how to store data in a session. Can you [edit] your answer to include that?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel fires an event when a new login is made to the application.
When an event fires  you may add a listener for it, then  add a session .
This is the content of a listener I made.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Listeners\Auth;

 use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class UserLoggedIn
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }


    public function handle(Login $event)
    {

        if ($event->user->hasRole('subsidiary_admin')) {



            \Session::put('subsidiary_admin', $event->user->subsidiaryBoUser->subsidiary_id);
            \Session::put('subsidiary', $event->user->subsidiaryBoUser->subsidiary);



        }






    }
}
```

and I register it on the `eventServiceProvider` like this

```html
 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
            'App\Listeners\Auth\UserLoggedIn',
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store data in the session using two different methods either a Request instance or using the global helper/function provided.

**Request Instance**

```
public function methodA(Request $request) {
    $request->session()->put('KEY', 'VALUE');
}
```

**Global Helper**

```
public function methodB() {
    session(['key' => 'value']);
}
```

You can find more details on both methods in the [**documentation**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#storing-data).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am doing:

I have this on my helper file:

**\App\Helpers\helpers.php:**

```
function signedUser()
{
  return [
    'id'           => Auth::id(),
    'group_id'     => Auth::user()->group_id,
    'group_name'   => Auth::user()->group->name,
    'avatar'       => Auth::user()->avatar,
    'first_name'   => Auth::user()->first_name,
    'full_name'    => Auth::user()->full_name,
  ];
}
```

**On my User Model:**

```
public function group()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Group');
}

public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
   $full_name = ucfirst($this->first_name) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->middle_name[0]) . '. ' . ucfirst($this->last_name);

   return $full_name;
}
```

Then I can accessed the variables on both controllers and blade files like so:

```
dump(signedUser()['full_name']);

{{ signedUser()['full_name'] }}
```